# problems with slice() on react-redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am trying to copy a state with slice(), then manipulate it and create a new state

this is my Reducer:

```
case types.LOAD_AMOUNT_CHECKINS_SUCCESS: {
        let buildings = state.buildings.slice();

        buildings['devices_error'] = action.checkins['error];
        .
        .
        .
        return Object.assign({}, state,
            {buildings: buildings}
        );
    }
```

but applying slice() returns me: []

Where I have the error?

Comment: What is the value of your `state.buildings` array before slicing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `state.buildings` is an object (and not an array), change the second line to this:

```
case types.LOAD_AMOUNT_CHECKINS_SUCCESS: {
    let buildings = Object.assign({}, state.buildings);

    buildings['devices_error'] = action.checkins['error];
    .
    .
    .
    return Object.assign({}, state,
        { buildings: buildings }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To make a shallow copy you can call slice() on arrays only 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice

In you code example you are calling it on the object not on the array.